# Error connecting to TPM Chip - ASUS ROG

Tags: boot, dual-boot, tpm

I dual booted ubuntu 18.04 with windows 10 on my laptop. it was working fine until one day it just started showing this error: "Error connecting to tpm chip". I have tried following the online fixes - turning on the TPM chip from the BIOS but there is no TPM chip option available in the BIOS. Please help!
Following are my laptop specs:
ASUS ROG
Intel core i7
Nvidia GTX 1660
16gb RAM

Comment: This error points to issues with the graphics card drivers. You may need to choose "Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)" from the Grub menu, then reinstall/reconfigure your graphics drivers from there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. on my Grub menu, i dont have the safe graphics option showing up. I went into the advanced options and tried to boot in the recovery mode but got another error: "gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:..."

Comment: Also note there is no version 18 in Ubuntu.Maybe it is 18.04?

Comment: yes you are right. apologies for the mistake. i have edited the statement. would appreciate any help