# Delete Ubuntu Dual boot - Unable to Delete Linux Partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uninstall, windows-10, disk-management

I had Ubuntu 18.04 running perfectly fine on my laptop with Windows 10. Recently I ran into an issue and decided to uninstall Ubuntu and install it again later. To do so, I changed the boot preference to Windows boot loader in the UEFI Firmware settings and then I went to disk management to delete the space occupied by Ubuntu. I had three partitions for Ubuntu: root, swap and home. I was able to delete 1 volume only and cant see the option to delete rest of the volumes.

[image: here]

The reason I decided to uninstall Ubuntu was that when booting into Ubuntu, I used to get a blank screen with the following error: "Error connecting to TPM chip." I tried solving that by booting into recovery mode but that too yielded no results.

- [Error connecting to TPM Chip - ASUS ROG](https://askubuntu.com/q/1316673/1117359)
- [Unable to boot in recovery mode - dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1316747/1117359)

I have listed the issues just in case it helps someone solving the issue.

Comment: You may want to change the title it says you are trying to delete Windows 10. The question says you are trying to delete Ubuntu. What is it?

Comment: Please use "edit" to clarify your question. In addition, please include images directly into the question - there is a function for that.

Comment: I have changed the title. Can you advice how to add images directly into questions?